# Confluent Control Center is not starting

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

confluent control center is not starting.

I executed following commands to start Confluent platform

1. Zookeeper start (Terminal 1)
2. Kafka start (Terminal 2)
3. Schema Registry Start (Terminal 3)
4. Then I tried to start Control Center (Terminal 4). But got Error. Its not starting.

```
    [2019-10-30 08:58:36,331] INFO [main] unable to get command store (io.confluent.command.CommandStore)
    [2019-10-30 08:58:37,331] INFO [main] unable to get command store (io.confluent.command.CommandStore)
    [2019-10-30 08:58:37,331] WARN [main] unable to start with allowance=300000 (io.confluent.command.CommandStore)
    [2019-10-30 08:58:37,332] ERROR [main] failed to start topology (io.confluent.controlcenter.ControlCenter)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at io.confluent.command.CommandStore.start(CommandStore.java:108)
        at io.confluent.controlcenter.ControlCenter.main(ControlCenter.java:124)
```

Comment: you can update the control center id in your properties file

Comment: Were you able to start the Confluent Control Center?

Comment: worked by updating control center id in properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worked by updating control center id in properties file

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/3715185/styps

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

1. Open ~/etc/confluent-control-center/control-center.properties
2. Uncomment '#confluent.controlcenter.id=1'
3. Run 'confluent local services start'